# C# : How to print DateTimePicker and fetch date value in botframework?

Tags: c#, botframework, formflow

I'm making a bot using MS bot framework and this is a formflow I'm using to take details from the user to make an appointment.

Is there a way to display a datetimepicker instead of making the user type in the date and time. And then take and store the value the user enters in the picker in a variable?

```
public class ScheduleApp
{
    [Prompt("What is your First Name? {||}")]
    public string FirstName;
    [Prompt("What is your Last Name? {||}")]
    public string LastName;
    [Prompt("What is your email address? {||}")]
    public string Email;
    [Prompt("What is your Contact number? {||}")]
    public string mobilePhone;
    [Prompt("What is your Gender? Male or Female {||}")]
    public string Gender;
    [Prompt("What is your Age? {||}")]
    public string Age;
    [Prompt("What is the date for the appointment? {||}")]
    public DateTime Date1;
    [Prompt("Any comments {||}")]
    public string Comment;

    public static IForm<ScheduleApp> BuildForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<ScheduleApp>()
            .Message("I just need a few details to schedule the appointment ")
            .Build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I am also facing same..

Comment: In which channel do you want to do it?